# How to detect only the water or solution inside of the beaker in image. (OPENCV)

Tags: c++, opencv3.0

I am trying to find the region where it only has the solution/water in the beaker.

All images are converted into grayscale images and the other than a beaker and solution are all white pixels.

So one of the ideas was to find the vertical boundary and horizontal boundary to compute only the solution, and crop that region and saves it as a rectangle. but how to implement it would be my question.

I think the manual way is to start indexing from the middle point of images and try to find the non-white pixels.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you saying you have a photograph of a beaker with some amount of liquid in it and you want to determine the volume of the liquid? Or you just want a visual mask of the liquid?

Comment: yes that's correct. the image contains the liquid in the beaker and their surroundings

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `cv::watershed` function that does image segmentation.

Here is also a tutorial that uses the function to isolate objects:

https://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d2/dbd/tutorial_distance_transform.html